# Thread creation will stop working after some time

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, debian, pthreads

I am using Linux

```
void *threadStart()
{
    int threadClose;
    led = 1;
    delay(10);
    led = 0;
    pthread_exit(&threadClose);
}

main()
{
    pthread_t thread1;
    while(1)
    {
        pthread_create(&thread1,NULL,threadStart,NULL);
        /* calling some function calls here */
    }
}
```

This is my C code. When I compiled it, this will successfully compile and when I run this program the LED starts blinking after sometimes. The LED will stop the blinking and the `pthread_create()` function returns an error.

Anything I did wrong or any suggestions?

Comment: Please describe more about the way your problem happens. Is it stopping by not changing the led? Is it stopping by crashing? Is it stopping with an error message? Crash? Reset? How often is the thread creation called? More often than once every `delay(10)`? Also, please make your code quote compileable, by changing the non-code to comments (and fix the indentation while you are at it).

Comment: My tip: you do not call `pthread_join` or `pthread_detach` in the main thread.

Comment: An (IMO) even better tip: don't create a new thread every time you want to blink the LED *once*.

Comment: I need to blink LEDs once at each time inside while loop starts.

Comment: How does the LED blink?  If it's setting/clearing a GPIO pin, it's a simple, quick and non-blocking operation that does not need another thread.  If the LED is the other side of the world and connected via a client/server, you should probably mention that:)

Answer (score 2):

When a thread is created it consumes resources, global resources, typically memory, for the thread's stack for example.

Those resources are freed when the tread ends *and* if one of the following two actions are taken

- `pthread_join()` is called, passing the thread's ID.
- the thread is detached. This can be done any time after the tread had been created using `pthread_detach()`, passing the thread's ID.

The code you show does perform none of the two above actions.

As a consequence the program creating those thread's (inside the `while`-loop) sooner or later runs out of resources to create any new thread, hence `pthread_create()` starts failing.